# прилагательные от существительных

Tags: прилагательные

прилагательное  от  слова  часть

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от контекста - частный или частичный. Значения, естественно, разные.
Частный вопрос. Частный интерес. Частная собственность. Частичное выполнение.